# Scheme for calculating Momentum $\times$ Position

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Consider an object $O$ in 3-space. It is possible to either measure the momentum of $O$ or the position of $O$ but not both beyond some level of accuracy.

Hypothetically one may be interested in knowing the value of the vector $L = X \times P$ however a naive scheme of calculating position and momentum would lead to a challenge since due to Heisenberg we have

$$ \sigma_X \sigma_P \ge \frac{\hbar}{2}$$

And therefore, if we use an experimental set up of "measuring" momentum and position simultaneously we end up with the following error term: $$ \sigma_L \ge |P|\sigma_X + |X|\sigma_P +\frac{\hbar}{2}$$

Which would be disastrously inaccurate when conducting experiments over large distances or involving large momenta.

Additionally Given that $L$ by itself doesn't convey information about position or momentum, there shouldn't really be a bound AT ALL on how accurately it can be measured by itself which suggests there should be some class of non trivial experiments that can do this without directly measuring position or momentum.

What would be an example of such an experiment, and more generally, is it possible to "derive" such an experiment algorithmically, without the use of intuition?

Comment: ???   You start off doing something like classical mechanics ("$O$ has a well defined momentum vector and position vector" and then in the next paragraph you're invoking Heisenberg uncertainty.  What theory are you using?

Comment: That first sentence was very lazy on my part, what i meant to really say was "its possible to measure O's momentum, or O's position"

Comment: @WillO please look at changes to sentence, and hopefully if satisfactory would you be willing to remove the downvote? If not, please let me know what else is in need of improvement/clarification

Comment: The total angular momentum $\vec{L}$ is known exactly for a lot of things.. electrons in orbitals for example.

Comment: I don't get the bit about how there is no bound on the accuracy with which $L$ can be measured.   This is true, but it's also of course of both $P$ and $X$, so what distinction are you making?

Comment: @WillO the distinction i'm making is that we can arbtrarily accurately measure $P$ or $X$ and like you noted, we should be able to for $L$. But if we do an experiment of the type, 1. measure momentum somehow, 2. measure position somehow, 3. multiply. Then that rather large error term I have listed there, comes into effect. So "how do I make an experiment that circumvents that" is the question.

Comment: So----Is your question simply "What experiment can I do to measure $|L|$?"  (You can't, of course, measure the vector $L$ because of the uncertainty principle, as @SeñorO has already pointed out.  It's a good exercise to verify this by computing the commutators of the components.)

Answer (score 1):

You can know $|\vec{L}|$ exactly - an example is an electron orbital in the hydrogen atom. You can see by $\vec{L}^2 |\psi> = l(l+1)|\psi>$ that $|\vec{L}| = \sqrt{l(l+1)}$

However, you **cannot** know $\vec{L}$ exactly (meaning $L_x, L_y, \text{and } L_z $) - only **one** of those three components (by convention we set the one we can know to the z-axis when possible). If you were to know all three components, you could work out x and p backwards.